# Interface translation of custom fields

Tags: i18n-l10n

When I translate field labels via admin/config/regional/translate/translate then my changes are happening in the frontend - but this does not work for fields which I created myself. Those fields are available for translation in the same spot but changes to them have no effect - it always uses the original text.

In my case it's about some additional fields in the registration form. I have de/user/register and fr/user/register and the pre-existing fields are in the correct language and if I do changes to them, then they are applied. But if I provide translations for the fields which I added, then they just don't show up.

I am using Drupal 7.14. On the picture, you see the custom field "wohnort". The first one has been there right after the creation of the custom field; the second one only after the Field Translation module and the i18n pack.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is **Internationalization** pack for building multilingual sites in Drupal: [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n).
To translate field labels you need *“Field translation”* module from this pack. After you enable it new tab “Translate” appears on field edit page.

[image]

### Update

That's strange that you can see your field labels on `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` page, so I started an issue [#1672694](http://drupal.org/node/1672694). I think it's a bug.

### Update 2

Fixed since [Drupal 7.22](http://drupal.org/drupal-7.22-release-notes)

Comment: Thank you very much kalabro. I already had i18n installed but it has so many modules and there is so much stuff around it that i just didn't get it.  -- However I'm still quite interested why it didn't work without that module, I think that it should. Otherwise I don't see the reason why the system even gives me the option to save a translation for my custom fields.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It will work if you wrap your labels output with `t()` function but it's bad practice because `t()` is for static strings in your code.

Comment: But i still don't quite get it - why can those strings be found in the translate module if it doesn't change a thing what i put in there. And I'm not coding the output, I didn't change a thing about the output I just added some fields to the registration form.